# Sunrise Calendar Alternative

Tags: android, calendar

Strange that no one asked this question as [Sunrise](https://calendar.sunrise.am/) is about to shut down.

This is more a question for people who actually used Sunrise and like its style. I am wondering if any of you have used any good alternative for Sunrise which includes a few major features that sunrise has:

- Does not force to pick up all calendars accounts in your device but
  instead allow separate accounts to be added into the app
- Multi-platform, e.g. OSX
- Good user experience in app and also importantly - notifications

Comment: If you can live without the multi-platform part, [Business Calendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appgenix.bizcal) would be a good match: Reminders are independent from the Google calendar, you can pick the calendars to be shown, and it's really nice to work with. I'm using it for years (the Pro version) and am very satisfied. Good support as well.

Comment: I will  remove this comment. Actually, I wanted to ask the same question, but found popcm's question to be here already. I thought, asking the same question twice was not a good thing to do. Hence, I want to support the question which is already in existence. ppcm explicitly asks for a Sunrise replacement. Sunrise supports Trello. I wanted to point this out... Anyway, leaves me a bit puzzled, to be honest.

Comment: I just wanted to ask exactly the same question. Looking for Sunrise alternatives, too!

Answer (score 2):

Having spent quite a few hours in research, I finally came across a new and shiny calendar app called [Kin](https://kin.today/). I'm using the web app as a Chromium Application with Ubuntu Linux 16.04.

According to their website, the aim of the developer is to *let the sun rise again*, which is pretty straight forward in my opinion. Anyway, much appreciated!

I've registered to become a beta tester and have just today (Aug 18) received an email to start testing. Very first impression is good. The user interface reminds me on Sunrise's interface, which is not a bad thing, though.

So far, I've connected with my Google Calendar and with my Trello Boards. Everything seems to work fine.

Of course, there are a lot of features still missing, e.g. 24h time format. But I'm quite certain, this will be added soon.

Good luck to the guys from Kin!

Comment: 2019, and it's still in development, it seems.

Comment: Yepp, did never seem to gain enough traction finally ...