# Desktop web calendar with Google and Exchange support

Tags: calendar, synchronization, outlook, google-calendar

Now that Sunrise Calendar is dying, many will be left without a proper solution. What is the best solution? Requirements:

a desktop web page calendar with Google and Exchange data view and edit support
free (or if it costs something, it has to be really good)
Sunrise Calendar met these requirements but will be closed on Aug 31, 2016. I've searched and it seems there is no solution.

http://outlookgooglecalendarsync.codeplex.com/ is a free syncing tool but I'm not going to use that because that would have to be installed on every computer and adds complexity. Another workaround is to use iPhone Google Calendar with the operating system's calendars which means Exchange is also supported there. But the point is that I want to view and edit both Google Calendar events and Exchange Calendar events from a web page in one place, from any computer.

Office 365's web version of Outlook is able to view iCal (.ics) data, which can be retrieved from Google Calendar and Outlook. Visually it's pretty ok looking different colors in one calendar. But it's not able to edit neither Google Calendar data nor external Exchange data (which Sunrise was capable of).

Google Calendar's web version can also view Exchange calendars (when entering the .ics link to Google Calendar's Settings / Calendars / Browse interesting calendars / Add by URL), but again no editing for other accounts. AND, basically it works only for entries made/edited 24 hours ago because the data is fetched only once per day, it seems. And there is a bug that prevents calendar data edits from updating. That causes deleted events still appearing etc. The same problem seems to apply for the previous Outlook solution.

What's the best solution?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/32336/sunrise-calendar-alternative

Comment: Wow, thanks, Kin https://kin.today/ seems extremely promising. Currently at beta stage.